# Python : Cryptography Fernet : Reduce length of encrypted text generated

Tags: python, cryptography, fernet

I am using Cryptography Fernet for encryption and decryption. After encrypting data, it's length is to huge, is there any way to reduce it length or limit it?

**Example** : gAAAAABgUZeX2ffM7H07MfyZ2FGPj2xPSPbN0r3rQ1BzfKHsJ7QFUOgsqoOjOAh6Ksq-9fDCrLxb32g0NPbbU6F7lZeSk7Xfgj-2vHHtTjxd3rj02qWGoaQ=

```
def encrypt(message):
    encoded_message = message.encode()
    f = Fernet(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    encrypted_message = f.encrypt(encoded_message)

    return encrypted_message.decode()
```

Comment: 120 bytes is *huge*? What are the constraints of your environment that require a smaller payload? If you can send arbitrary binary payloads then you can do away with the base64 encoding and shrink that 120 bytes down to 90.

Comment: Using a block cipher mode that requires padding will increase the size up to the next block boundary.  Use CTR mode or similar to avoid the need for padding.  Any mode with authentication, like GCM, will need extra space for the authentication data.  A prepended IV will also increase the output size. Using Base64, as you appear to be doing, increases the final output size as @President James K. Polk pointed out.

Comment: GCM is CTR mode plus a MAC built in, so it already doesn't have data padding.  There isn't really a secure way to not use an IV or not have integrity protection like with an AEAD or an added MAC, and honestly compared to HMAC an AEAD is going to be smaller.

Comment: The 120-byte example isn't great, but the question is worthwhile as the Python `cryptography` library's Fernet scheme can be used for much larger payloads.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way I think is to base64-decode the Fernet output to binary, as suggested in [the comment by “Pres. Polk”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667705/python-cryptography-fernet-reduce-length-of-encrypted-text-generated#comment117858996_66667705). This means that, instead of `return encrypted_message.decode()`, do:

```py
# import base64
return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encrypted_message)
```

This is if your use case allows binary data, of course, and it will save ~25% space. (That's the nature of base64 encoding.) As this is already encrypted data, further compression won't work. You *could* compress the data *before* encrypting, but be aware that it can weaken the encryption somewhat; see [this cryptography Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/33755), and then the counterargument in [this infosec Q&A](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/43413).

Do note that if you will mainly be dealing with small amounts of data as in your example (a 120-char Fernet token implies your original data is less than 32 bytes, if I'm not mistaken), then maybe you shouldn't bother at all. It only looks “huge” relative to your original data because of the metadata and padding required in Fernet's encryption scheme (as detailed by the other comments), but with longer messages, the overhead will be almost entirely due to the base64 encoding (i.e. ~33% more). In those cases, with decoding to binary, the output will be almost the same length as your original data.

There is actually another less-efficient option: use compression on the base64-encoded output string, e.g., `zlib.compress(encrypted_message)`. But this also produces binary data, and, more importantly, it's already done automatically in many environments that handle text (e.g. on the web).